# Overwrite row data in one sheet with data from a second sheet satisfying 4 conditions

Tags: vba, excel

I've looked at several threads and there are some that touch on my problem, however, I've never used VBA and haven't a clue how to change the coding to suit my problem.

I would like to overwrite rows of data on sheet 2 from sheet 1, providing the data in columns A, B, C & D (live data starting row 2) are a match on both sheets 1 & 2.

Essentially sheet 2 is my data store, and sheet 1 is a template of sheet 2. All the possible combinations of data in the first four columns already exist in sheet 2 with the remaining data in the row unknown. So when I get that unknown data, I would like to overwrite that row in sheet 2.

A lot of people have made threads about copying rows over where one specific term is searched for in a column, whereas, I will have many different terms to search for, but as I said, they will need to be a match on both sheets.

Hope I've made sense! Please help!

Comment: If you do not know VBA I think it will be better to go to freelance sites and post this as a job and you will get it done very quickly with spending small amount of money. Otherwise please provide what you have tried and where have you stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do this with a formula rather than using VBA.

Paste this formula into cell E1 of sheet1 if you have no headers:

```
=IF(AND(A1=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE)),B1=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(B1,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE)), C1=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(C1,Sheet2!C:C,FALSE)),D1=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(D1,Sheet2!D:D,FALSE))),INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE)),"NO")
```

Or this one into E2 if you have a header row:

```
=IF(AND(A2=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE)),B2=INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!B:B,FALSE)), C2=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(C2,Sheet2!C:C,FALSE)),D2=INDEX(Sheet2!D:D,MATCH(D2,Sheet2!D:D,FALSE))),INDEX(Sheet2!E:E,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A:A,FALSE)),"NO")
```

Then drag that across using the little toggle on the bottom right of the cell as far across sheet1 as you want the columns to come in from your sheet2.

Then highlight the whole row you just created and drag the little toggle at the bottom right as far down the sheet as you have data (or try double clicking the toggle to auto fill down).

I tried this on a small set of data and it seems to work so it should work for your larger data set as long as all possible variations of the 4 columns on sheet1 are available on sheet2 with associated data in the following columns.

If you get a result of "NO" in any cell then Excel can't find a row in sheet2 which has the exact combination matching the one on sheet1.

EDIT - UPDATED ANSWER BELOW.

Try this, which is much more likely to work for you.

```
Sub CopyItOver()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    For Each c1 In sh1.Range("A1", sh1.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        For Each c2 In sh2.Range("A1", sh2.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
            If c2.Value = c1.Value Then
                If c2.Offset(0, 1).Value = c1.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                    If c2.Offset(0, 2).Value = c1.Offset(0, 2).Value Then
                        If c2.Offset(0, 3).Value = c1.Offset(0, 3).Value Then
                            c1.EntireRow.Value = c2.EntireRow.Value
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next c2
    Next c1

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get this method to work. I have created an extra column for this formula in column E, sheet 1, pushing the remaining columns out (F through AA). I have done the same in sheet 2 to avoid data the data overwriting into the wrong cells. When the formula runs, it prompts me to open a file (I assume to have a target to update?) I clicked on the relevant sheet in the workbook but it doesn't seem to like it, it does the same thing when I try to drag the cell along or down. After that I get an error message from excel telling me to use the insert function option.

Comment: Are your sheets named Sheet1 and Sheet2 or something else?

Comment: Update -

I had made a mistake when changing the name of 'sheet2' for my worksheet, I forgot the commas around the name of the sheet. I also included dollar signs around the Index arrays as they were changing when I was dragging the cell.

Unfortunately though, still not working, there's no file prompt now but all the cells just read #N/A

Comment: Apologies, that hastily written function most likely won't work as it's evaluating each index/match as true/false independently so it will give you some odd results. I've updated my answer with a piece of VBA code which should hopefully give you the result you're after.

Comment: The VBA works like a dream, and a lot shorter than I thought it would be.

Thank you Harley!